# Spring Batch Partition Threads Not Executing together

Tags: spring-batch, threadpool

We have spring batch job reading XML files and inserting to DB. Each batch slave partition is taking 10000 XML's and writing to DB.

Below is the Thread pool configuration

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(80);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(50);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(30);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

We are partitioning into 30 chunks and commit of 100 for each threads. All the 30 threads are inserting into table BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION says starting. Few completes in seconds with same number of records and others are waiting and takes  3 to 7 minutes. Application configuration is 6GB memory and Linux 64 bit having 96 CPU.

Server Configuration
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                96
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-95
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    24
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8160M CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:              4

[image: See the attached last threads are waiting]

Comment: `Each batch slave partition is taking 10000 XML's and writing to DB [...] We are partitioning into 30 chunks and commit of 100 for each threads`: So each worker step is processing 10.000 xml files and you have 30 partitions, correct? Please share your code to be able to understand your setup.

Comment: Please find the Job step config file above. We have 30 partitions and each partition is processing 10000 xml files.

Comment: Please also let me know I can increase number of worker step to 60 and memory to 8GB to improve performance

Comment: I see that an item = the entire xml file loaded in memory + other data (environment). With 30 partitions and chunk size = 100, this means you can have 3000 xml files loaded in memory at once. I'm not sure this is the best option to tackle your file ingestion use case, especially if your xml files are big. This inefficient memory usage is probably your issue (a lot of GC, long transactions, etc)..

Comment: If I understand correctly, your issue is: `Few completes in seconds with same number of records and others are waiting and takes 3 to 7 minutes`. I can't see from what you shared why this is happening, but probably due to inefficient memory usage as explained in my previous comment. I suggest you run your job in debug mode (and activate GC logs) and see where each partition is spending most of its time.

Comment: Thank you for the support. Could you also review below points. Is it because of  Isolation.READ_COMMITTED instead of  SERIALIZABLE.  Do this have any performance impact. What is advise to use 60 threads with 100 connection pool to improve performance.

Comment: Dear Mahmoud , Identified the issue. We are creating slaves of 30 but master grid configuration is missing and default its taking 6 threads parallel. Remaining starting after completing 6.

Comment: Step masterStep() throws Exception {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner()).step(slaveStep())
    .gridSize(30).taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).listener(new InvoiceStepListener()).build();

Comment: Please comment on above as it will help others and you are the master for this.

Comment: `Identified the issue`: glad you find your issue. Now that you increased the grid size to 30 with `.gridSize(30)`, do this fixes your problem? What do you want me to comment on? I really recommend providing a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this kind of issues to help others help you in an efficient way. You only shared the configuration of your taskExecutor, but if you have shared your job/step config we could have identified the issue more quickly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion if i mentioned anything wrongly. We have asked the advise to make sure the fix we applied is correct and will clarify the difference between grid size and partitions. Thank you so much for the support of this wonderful framework and performance optimizations(1 milllion/1hour). We will make sure to add minimal examples